# C++ List within Class to store user input

Tags: c++, list, class, parameters, getter

It's been some time since I last wrote code, but I'm trying to dust off the few skills I had gained while studying. For now, I'm just trying to implement solutions to statements/questions I see online.

For this I'm trying to build an allergy class that will store information (category, name, symptoms) provided by user input. I started by just taking string input for each parameter, but in the real world, people may have multiple symptoms. For that, i want to create a list parameter for symptoms instead of a single string. Here are my files:

Allergy.hpp:

```
    #ifndef Allergy_hpp
    #define Allergy_hpp

    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <list>
    using namespace std;


    class Allergy {
    public:

        Allergy();
        Allergy(string, string, list <string>);
        ~Allergy();

        //getters
        string getCategory() const;
        string getName() const;
        list <string> getSymptom() const;


    private:

        string newCategory;
        string newName;
        list <string> newSymptom;
    };

    #endif /* Allergy_hpp */
```

Allergy.cpp:

```
#include "Allergy.hpp"

Allergy::Allergy(string name, string category, list <string> symptom){
    newName = name;
    newCategory = category;
    newSymptom = symptom;
}

Allergy::~Allergy(){

}

//getters

string Allergy::getName() const{
    return newName;
}

string Allergy::getCategory() const{
    return newCategory;
}


list Allergy::getSymptom() const{
    return newSymptom;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Allergy.hpp"

using namespace std;



int main() {
    string name;
    string category;
    string symptom;

    cout << "Enter allergy name: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Enter allergy category: ";
    getline(cin, category);
    cout << "Enter allergy symptom: ";
    getline(cin, symptom);

    Allergy Allergy_1(name, category, symptom);
    cout << endl << "Allergy Name: " << Allergy_1.getName() << endl <<
    "Allergy Category: " << Allergy_1.getCategory() <<  endl <<
    "Allergy Symptom: " << Allergy_1.getSymptom() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I haven't made it to the implementation in main.cpp. For now I'm stuck creating a getter for the list within Allergy.cpp. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of the getter's implementation doesn't match the signature in the class definition:

```
list Allergy::getSymptom() const{  // <===  oops!!
    return newSymptom;
}
```

Just correct this:

```
list<string> Allergy::getSymptom() const{  // <===  yes !!
    return newSymptom;
}
```

**Edit:**

Even if the getter will now compile, you can't just display the list of symptoms like this:

```
cout << endl << "Allergy Name: " << Allergy_1.getName() << endl <<
    "Allergy Category: " << Allergy_1.getCategory() <<  endl <<
    "Allergy Symptom: " << Allergy_1.getSymptom() << endl;
```

To print the symptoms, either use a range-for, which is an easy way to iterate through a list:

```
for (auto& s : Allergy_1.getSymptom()) {
    cout << s<<" "; 
}
```

Or use a copy with an ostrea_iterator:

```
auto mylist=Allergy_1.getSymptom(); 
copy (mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout," "));
```

Comment: Thank you!! I caught the getter error shortly after posting - doh. Thanks for the pro tip on printing the list. Can you explain the for loop a little more? - it defiantly works, but I don't want to use something I don't understand.

Comment: The for-range loops through the elements of a container (after the `:`) with a content variable (here s, and I don't want to bother with the type, so I put auto).  More info here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for